# Code based Serilog configuration in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, serilog

I am following the [guidelines](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Code/Debugging/Logging/#full-c-control-over-serilog-configuration) for configuring Serilog via C# instead of through a config file. This is for an **Umbraco 8** application.

The guidelines specify that I need to inherit from UmbracoApplication and then override the GetLogger() method:

```
public class FineTuneLogging : UmbracoApplication
{
    protected override ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();
        loggerConfig
            .Enrich.WithProperty("MyProperty", "whatIWant")
            .MinimalConfiguration()
            .OutputDefaultTextFile(LogEventLevel.Error)
            .OutputDefaultJsonFile(LogEventLevel.Information)
            .ReadFromConfigFile()
            .ReadFromUserConfigFile();

        return new SerilogLogger(loggerConfig);
    }
}
```

However, GetLogger() is not found in the inheritance tree.

Are the docs out of date or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you change the global asax as it says right underneath?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah, didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Just so I won't keep asking, did you do the whole parade, you know, change asax, clean rebuild etc?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah, clean, rebuild etc. Problem is GetLogger() cannot be overriden in my custom class as it does not exist on UmbracoApplication to override.

Comment: Bring it here: https://our.umbraco.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be overriding `GetRuntime`

```
public class FineTuneLogging : UmbracoApplication
{
    protected override IRuntime GetRuntime()
    {
        return new FineTuneLoggingRuntime(this);
    }
}

public class FineTuneLoggingRuntime : WebRuntime
{
    public FineTuneLoggingRuntime(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication) : base(umbracoApplication) { }

    protected override ILogger GetLogger()
    {
        var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();
        loggerConfig
            .Enrich.WithProperty("MyProperty", "whatIWant")
            .MinimalConfiguration()
            .OutputDefaultTextFile(LogEventLevel.Error)
            .OutputDefaultJsonFile(LogEventLevel.Information)
            .ReadFromConfigFile()
            .ReadFromUserConfigFile();

        return new SerilogLogger(loggerConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky It was correct at some point - then they refactored the code and never updated the docs.